# Como fazer um @foreach com Relacionamento de Tabelas no Laravel

Tags: laravel, select, foreach, relacionamento

Estou utilizando o freamwork Laravel onde no meu banco de dados tenho 2 tabelas:
 -> reclamantes (com o campo 'id','reclamante','tipoacoes_id')
 -> tipoacoes (com os campos 'id', 'nome')

Ambos já estão com o Relacionamento na Model Reclamante

```
public function tipoacao(){
    return $this->hasMany(TipoAcoes::class, 'id', 'tipoacao_id');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id){
    $titulo = "Edita Reclamante";
    $reclamantes = $this->reclamante->find($id);
    return view('admin.reclamante.create-edit', compact('titulo','reclamantes'));
}
```

Mas não estou conseguindo trazer os dados com campo 'nome' da tabela 'tipoacoes'
dentro de um imput select

```
     <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" id="tipoacao_id" name="tipoacao_id" required value="{{$reclamantes->tipoacao->nome or old('$reclamantes->tipoacao->nome')}}">
               @foreach($reclamantes as $Rel)
                    <option value="{{$Rel->tipoacao->id}}">{{$Rel->tipoacao->nome}}</option>
               @endforeach
            </select>
```

Comment: Acho que você consegue formular uma pergunta melhor. Talvez com códigos de exemplo (talvez o que esteja usando), ou um questionamento mais claro. Da forma que está fica muito difícil te ajudar

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Sou novo por aqui esse é minha primeira pergunta rs... Acho que com seu conselho deu p/ detalhar mais!

Answer (score 2):

Na sua controller creio que a sua consulta está sendo feita de maneira errada. O `$this` faz uma referência à classe atual, no seu caso, a controller. Então o `$this->reclamante` não resultaria em nada. O correto seria:

```
public function edit($id){
    $titulo = "Edita Reclamante";
    $reclamantes = Reclamante::find($id);
    return view('admin.reclamante.create-edit', compact('titulo','reclamantes'));
}
```

Não se esqueça de declarar o use da Model Reclamante.

Após essa consulta, dentro de seu $reclamantes terá a referência ao tipoacao, então basta percorrer essa opção dentro de sua variável `$reclamantes` e obter os campos.

```
@foreach($reclamantes->tipoacao as $tipoacao)
    <option value="{{$tipoacao->id}}">{{$tipoacao->nome}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Lembrando que estou assumindo que esses são os atributos e nomes criados em sua Model.

Comment: Minha Controller esta assim pois tem uma construct acima

    public function __construct(Reclamante $reclamante){
        $this->reclamante = $reclamante;
    }

Mas enfim, funcionou, coloquei o @foreach como vc espicificou e funcionou Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que você relacionou errado no seu Model. Você alterou a ordem dos parâmetros.

```
public function tipoacao(){
    return $this->hasMany( TipoAcoes::class, 'tipoacao_id', 'id'); // 1º parâmetro é a classe que vai relacionar, o 2º é a foreign_key e o 3º é a local_key
}
```

Dá uma olhada na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) para tirar qualquer dúvida.